# Sparse data leads to the xAxis labels overla and exceed the border in highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts, overlapping, axis-labels

Recently, I encounter a problem that is: I wanna draw a month-candle chart for stock data, and the time interval of series data is long as a month, when I move the navigator, maybe due to the data is too sparse, the xAxis data labels exceed The Yaxis vertical line and even reach the border!

```
navigator: {
            adaptToUpdatedData: false,
            xAxis: {
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    second: '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    minute: '%y-%m-%d %H:%M',
                    hour: '%y-%m-%d %H:%M',
                    day: '%Y-%m',
                    week: '%Y-%m',
                    month: '%Y',
                    year: '%Y'
                }
            }
        },

        scrollbar: {
            liveRedraw: false,
            enabled: true
        },

        xAxis: {
            ordinal: true,
            tickPixelInterval: 200,
            type: 'datetime',
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                second: '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                minute: '%y-%m-%d %H:%M',
                hour: '%y-%m-%d %H:%M',
                day: '%Y/%m/%d',
                week: '%Y/%m',
                month: '%Y/%m',
                year: '%Y'
            },
            labels: {
                maxStaggerLines: 1,
                align: 'center',
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5JD8F/

this link display the exceeding situations, and when I set the range of navigator very short (http://jsfiddle.net/ykg46/1/), not only the labels overlap with each other, but also the data in chart can not fill the entired chart, which only takes up the middle part of the chart,  I don`t know how to deal with this problem.

the twolinks above have the same code, expect the initial ranges of navigator are different, and please focus on the function: `getKchartOption()`and `drawKchart()` in the code, I am hoping for your kind help, and I will appreciate if anyone could give me the solution with a jsfiddle link.

Comment: Wow! By setting the xAxis.labels.overflow to false, the overlapping problem can be solved, but the situation of xAxis label exceeding the edge of Yaxis still exists......

Comment: Second one is a bug, reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2144 - try to use my workaround.